# Java 8: generic type inference fails on method reference?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, type-inference, ecj

Can anyone tell me why the following code fails to compile but the lambda version does:

Are there rules about the generic type inference? Anything I should avoid?

### Failed:

```java
EntityLayerManager.refreshLayerRenderables(
        wwd, this.networkNodeShapeLayer, nodeMap.values(),
        MissionDetailUIConst::createNetworkNodeRenderable,
        MissionDetailUIConst::updateNetworkNodeRenderable) // <<== FAILED
```

### Success (with normal lambda):

```java
EntityLayerManager.refreshLayerRenderables(
        wwd, this.networkNodeShapeLayer, nodeMap.values(),
        MissionDetailUIConst::createNetworkNodeRenderable,
        (e, coll) -> MissionDetailUIConst.updateNetworkNodeRenderable(e, coll));
```

### Success (with generic parameters specified):

```java
EntityLayerManager.<EwmsVwNetworkNodeEntity, KolladaRoot>refreshLayerRenderables(
        wwd, this.networkNodeShapeLayer, nodeMap.values(),
        MissionDetailUIConst::createNetworkNodeRenderable,
        MissionDetailUIConst::updateNetworkNodeRenderable)
```

### Referenced Methods:

```java
public static <E, R extends Renderable> int refreshLayerRenderables(WorldWindow wwd,
        RenderableLayer renderableLayer, Collection<E> entityList,
        Function<E, ? extends Collection<? extends R>> createRenderables,
        BiPredicate<E, Collection<R>> updateRenderables);

public static Collection<KolladaRoot> createNetworkNodeRenderable(EwmsVwNetworkNodeEntity networkNode);

public static boolean updateNetworkNodeRenderable(EwmsVwNetworkNodeEntity networkNode, Collection<KolladaRoot> colladaRootCollection);
```

Comment: Did you try with `BiPredicate<E, ? super Collection<R>>` in your `refreshLayerRenderables` ?

Comment: Can you include the full error message?

Comment: BiPredicate<E, ? super Collection<R>> failed too. The full message is "The type MissionDetailUIConst does not define updateNetworkNodeRenderable(E, Collection<R>) that is applicable here"

Comment: For questions like these it’s always recommended to include information about the compiler and its version used. Or, better, test with different compilers and include the results.

Comment: You should include the exact Generic type of `nodeMap`. Anyway, I tried to reproduce your setup as far as possible with all the missing types and the compiler accepted all three versions without errors (well, after inserting the missing semicolons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an Eclipse bug. I [narrowed it down](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441734) to the use of a nested generic parameter (`Collection<R>`) as the type of an argument (in `BiPredicate`) to the referenced method (specified as `Collection<KolladaRoot>`). It should compile fine in javac.exe.

I'd say stick with explicit type specification until it's [fixed in 4.5 M2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434483#c8), it should have less effect (if any) than switching to lambdas.